# Ubuntu not found in the boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I just installed Ubuntu from a USB Flash Drive half a hour ago, i let it all finish until it told me that to use Ubuntu i would need to reset my PC, and so i did.
However, it booted straight into Windows 7, and i saw that the partition completely disappeared from the "My PC" menu, however i went to the same program i used to make the partition and it is actually there, just completely nameless.

So i reset and hit TAB to see if it would appear in the boot menu, only Windows 7 appeared, what should i do to make Ubuntu appear on the list?

Specs: Pentium Dual-Core E5700 3Ghz (Supports 64-Bit)
2GB RAM
Intel G41 Express Chipset
and a 461GB HDD, with a second partition of 11GB
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS was the release i tried to install.

Comment: Windows does **not** recognize Linux partitions. That, however, is **not** the problem. Please edit your question, starting by the misleading title, and add your hardware specs and the Ubuntu release you tried to install, at least.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from the Ubuntu installer in "try before installing" mode. This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Nevermind, i just remembered i set it to "Something else" instead of "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 7" because i'm a moron. so yeah, this happened because of such thing, reinstalling right now.

Comment: Now it gives a problem about a CD-ROM even though i'm installing from USB, i give up, thanks for the help.